# Visual Studio Code - Can't find method RPCServer.Eval

Tags: debugging, go, visual-studio-code

When debugging GoLang in Visual Studio Code, once a break point is hit, typing anything such as "help" in the prompt (bottom) will return the below  error message.  Wondering if it is a configuration issue?

help
not available
2018/06/06 10:31:57 server.go:266: rpc: can't find method RPCServer.Eval

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, to fix it I added the following to the launch.json file:

`useAPIv1 : false`

On linux seems to be key sensitive. Take a look at this post where I found the information: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/51370